# How to fix the expected enum `Result`, found reference error in Rust

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have an interface as follows:

```
#[async_trait]
pub trait HttpClient {
    async fn send_request(&self, path: String) -> Result<Response, Error>;
}
```

Then in integration test, I have an implementation for it as follows:

```
struct MockClient {
    res_req: HashMap<String, Result<Response, Error>>
}
impl MockClient {
    pub fn mock(res_req: HashMap<String, Result<Response, Error>>) -> Self {
        Self {
            res_req,
        }
    }
}

#[async_trait]
impl HttpClient for MockClient {
    async fn send_request(&self, path: String) -> Result<Response, Error> {
        self.res_req.get(&path).unwrap()
    }
}
```

But his fails compilation with the following error

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> tests/integration_test.rs:22:9
   |
22 |         self.res_req.get(&path).unwrap()
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected enum `Result`, found reference
   |
   = note:   expected enum `Result<Response, reqwest::Error>`
           found reference `&Result<Response, reqwest::Error>`
```

I tried using `.clone()` to create a copy and returned but that did not work.

My questions are:

1. Why is the compilation error occuring?
2. Why did the attempt to use `clone()` not work?
3. How do I get this to compile?

Comment: `self.res_req.get(&path).unwrap()` returns a reference to a Result<Response, Error>,  but the method `send_request` is supposed to return a Result<Response, Error>
 `.clone()` does not work because `Result<T, E>` does not implement the Clone trait for either `T` or `E`.

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal, reproducible example? I've tried [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=da640a658479d3970626b2aa72a6e354) (I removed types that you didn't provide), and it produces the same error, but uncommenting the `.clone()` just works, so I'm not sure what your error is.

Comment: This is because Result doesn't have Clone (nor Copy) traits: [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=da640a658479d3970626b2aa72a6e354)